# How to handle/cast a recursive generic classes inheritance?

Tags: c#, generics, recursion

I will plot an example to illustrate my behind the scene issues.

Let say I have this base generic class :

```
public abstract class ContainerBase<T>
{
    Guid Id {get; init;}
    IList<T> Items {get; set;}
    bool IsLeaf {get; set;} = false;
    /// omitted constructors and so
}
```

Then I have a whole bunch (undefined number) of concrete Container class that have another `ContainerBase<...>` as the T type argument :

```
public class RootContainer : ContainerBase<ChildContainer1>
{...}

public class ChildContainer1: ContainerBase<ChildContainer2>
{...}

public class ChildContainer2: ContainerBase<ChildContainer3>
{...}

...

public class ChildContainerNminus1: ContainerBase<ChildContainerN>
{...}

public class ChildContainerN: ContainerBase<int> // the recursion end here.
{
    ...
    IsLeaf = true;
}
```

Now let say I have an `AddContainer` method from an Utility class and have access to the `RootContainer` object (a singleton for example) that is fully populated of recursive sub containers.

```
public static class ContainerUtility
{
    // What is the Type of the recursive currentContainer ?
    public static ContainerBase<T> FindContainer<T>(Guid id, ContainerBase<?> currentContainer)
    {
        if(currentContainer.Id == id)
            return currentContainer;

        if(currentContainer.IsLeaf) return default;

        foreach(var item in currentContainer.Items)
        {
            var potential = FindContainer(id, item);
            if(potential != default) return potential;
        }

        return default;
    }

    public static bool AddContainer<T>(ContainerBase<T> container, Guid parentId)
    {            
        // potential should be of container's parent type (ContainerBase<"T-1">)
        // but how to "bybass" an expected type parameter as I cannot know it ?

        var potential = FindContainer<?>(parentId, RootContainer.Instance)

        if(potential != default && potential is ContainerBase<?>) 
        {
            potential.Items.Add(container)
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You see, my issue is that I have a base type `ContainerBase` that is convenient for recursive search as all subClasses allow access to `Items` list to pursue recursion.

But at each step of the recursion it is a different actual type of `ContainerBase<?>`.
So I cannot perform cast on the method argument.

maybe use a top level interface that expose a `List<object> Items` ? Not sure that will end up good.

Comment: I think you've gone down the wrong route here. Even f you can adjust the input argument's generics to be right, the fact that you attempt to return a value obtained from a recursive call despite the non-recursive and recursive cases being at different levels means the return type isn't well formed. So this structure probably isn't the right solution to whatever problem you thought it would solve.

Comment: You might want to look at Eric Lippert's [Immutable Deque](https://ericlippert.com/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue/) which works as a recursive data structure - but note that when methods recurse, we're dealing with the *contained items*, not the *containers themselves* and the contained items aren't recursive types (or at least, not part of *this* recursive structure.

Answer (score 0):

*Bellow was my intermediate mid-solution on my issue.
I'll keep it for the record or erase it if you request it to clarify this response.*

Ok I get something more interesting now. I would like to have your criticism of this solution I end up with :

Mainly I abstracted a way higher with a non generic interface to avoid my issue described in OP.

**The Interface**

```
public interface IContainer
{
    int TAG { get; init; } // usefull for logging purpose

    string Name { get; }

    Guid Id { get; init; }
           
    public bool IsLeaf { get;}

    IList<IContainer>? GetContainers();

    void SetContainers(List<IContainer> value);
}
```

**The base class**

```
public abstract class ContainerBase<T> : IContainer where T : IContainer
{
    public int TAG { get; init; }

    public Guid Id { get; init; }

    private IList<IContainer>? _containers = new List<IContainer>();

    public IList<T> Items { get; set; } = new List<T>();

    public bool IsLeaf => this.GetType() == typeof(T);

    public string Name => this.GetType().Name + "_" + TAG;       

    public ContainerBase(Guid id)
    {
        TAG = ContainerUtils.ContainerCount++;
        Id=id;
    }

    public ContainerBase()
    {
        TAG = ContainerUtils.ContainerCount++;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public IList<IContainer>? GetContainers()
    {
        if(Items == null) return null;

        if(_containers == null || !_containers.Any())
            _containers = Items.Where(x => x!=null).Select(x => (IContainer)x!).ToList();

        return _containers;
    }

    public void SetContainers(List<IContainer> value)
    {
        Items = new List<T>();

        foreach(var item in value)
        {
            if (item is T)
                Items.Add((T)item);
        }            
    }
}
```

**The concrete classes**

```
internal class RootContainer : ContainerBase<Child1Container>
{
    public RootContainer(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    public RootContainer() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

The intermediate containers are the same only class name change (X = 1 to 3 in my test case)

```
internal class ChildXContainer : ContainerBase<ChildX+1Container>
{
    public ChildXContainer(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    public ChildXContainer() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

The leaf class (end point of my chained containers classes recursion).

```
internal class LeafContainer : ContainerBase<LeafContainer>
{
    public int IntItem { get; set; }
    
    public LeafContainer() : base()
    {            
    }

    public LeafContainer(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

Do note I'm using a trick to detect if a `ContainerBase<T>` concrete implementation is a leaf or not :
If such classes are leaves then they have to derive from `ContainerBase<>` of themselves.

Kind like the CRTP syntax, but without its meaning.

So I'm not fully satisfied of this trick, but better than my previous attempt so far.

**The Utility class**

```
internal static class ContainerUtils
{
    public static int ContainerCount = 0;

    public static Guid IdToSearch { 
        get
        {
            if(!AllIds.Any()) 
                return Guid.Empty;
            return AllIds[new Random().Next(AllIds.Count - 1)];
        }
        //set { IdToSearch = value; } 
    }

    public static List<Guid> AllIds { get; set; } = new();

    private static RootContainer _root = BuildContainers();

    public static RootContainer Root => _root;

    private static RootContainer BuildContainers()
    {
        LeafContainer Leaf = new LeafContainer();
        Child3Container Child3 = new Child3Container();
        Child2Container Child2 = new Child2Container();
        Child1Container Child1 = new Child1Container();
        RootContainer Root = new RootContainer();                  

        Root.Items.Add(Child1);
        Child1.Items.Add(Child2);
        Child2.Items.Add(Child3);
        Child3.Items.Add(Leaf);
        Leaf.IntItem = 12;

        AllIds.Add(Root.Id);
        AllIds.Add(Child1.Id);
        AllIds.Add(Child2.Id);
        AllIds.Add(Child3.Id);
        AllIds.Add(Leaf.Id);

        return Root;
    }

    private static IContainer? _GetSubContainer(this IContainer container, int index)
        => (container == null ||
            container.GetContainers() == null ||
            index >= container.GetContainers()!.Count) ? null : container.GetContainers()![index];

    public static string ContainersToString()
        => ContainersToString(Root);

    public static string ContainersToString(IContainer? fromContainer)
    {
        if (fromContainer == null) return string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        string tab = "  ";
        string res = "";
        while(fromContainer != null)
        {
            res += tab.Repeat(i) + "+" + fromContainer.Name??"NULL";
            res += "\n";
            i++;
            fromContainer = _GetSubContainer(fromContainer, 0);
        }

        return res;
    }       

    public static IContainer? SearchContainer(Guid id)
        => SearchContainer(id, Root);

    public static IContainer? SearchContainer(Guid id, IContainer? fromContainer)
    {
        if (fromContainer == null) return null;
        if (fromContainer.Id == id)
            return fromContainer;
        if (fromContainer.IsLeaf)
            return null;
        return SearchContainer(id, fromContainer._GetSubContainer(0));
    }

    public static bool SetItemToContainer(Guid id, IContainer newContainer) 
    {
        var container = SearchContainer(id);
        if(container == null) return false;

        if (container._GetSubContainer(0) == null || (container.GetContainers()![0].GetType() != newContainer.GetType()))
            return false;
        container.GetContainers()![0] = newContainer;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**The Program and its output**

```
Console.WriteLine(ContainerUtils.ContainersToString());

IContainer newChild2 = new Child2Container();

Console.WriteLine("Child2's Name : " + ContainerUtils.SearchContainer(ContainerUtils.AllIds[2])?.Name ?? "NULL");
Console.WriteLine("New Child2's Name : " + newChild2.Name);

ContainerUtils.SetItemToContainer(ContainerUtils.AllIds[1], newChild2);

Console.WriteLine(ContainerUtils.ContainersToString());
```

Output

> ```
> +RootContainer_4
>   +Child1Container_3
>     +Child2Container_2
>       +Child3Container_1
>         +LeafContainer_0
>     
> Child2's Name : Child2Container_2
> New Child2's Name : Child2Container_5
> +RootContainer_4
>   +Child1Container_3
>     +Child2Container_5
> ```

---

***OLD answer***

I created a new test project with a simpler version of my OP one.
Here is what I ended, and yep found using an interface as a "workish" solution (I'm not completely satisfied).
Let me know what you think of it please.

**The interface without generic parameter :**

```
public interface IContainer
{
    string Name => this.GetType().Name;

    public Guid Id { get; init; }

    public IContainer? Item { get; set; }

    public bool IsLeaf => Id == Guid.Empty;
}
```

**The base abstract class with the generic parameter :**

```
public abstract class ContainerBase<T> : IContainer where T : IContainer
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public T? Item { get; set; }
    IContainer? IContainer.Item { get => Item; set => Item = (T)value; }

    public ContainerBase(Guid id)
    {
        Id=id;
    }

    public ContainerBase()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

**The starting concrete `Container` class**

```
internal class RootContainer : ContainerBase<Child1Container>
{
    public RootContainer(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    public RootContainer() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

**The child `Container` concrete classes.**
In my project there is Child1Container, Child2Container and Child3Container. I only display `Child1Container` here. The other are the same except class name.

```
internal class Child1Container : ContainerBase<Child2Container>
{
    public Child1Container(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    public Child1Container() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

**The endind `Container` (noted Leaf here) :**
This is where I found the code most ugly..

```
internal class LeafContainer : IContainer
{
    public int IntItem { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; init ; }

    /// Meh, would be nice to avoid this.
    public IContainer? Item { get => null; set => Item = null; }

    public LeafContainer()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
    }
}
```

**My utility class :**

```
internal static class ContainerUtils
{
    public static Guid IdToSearch { get; set; }

    private static RootContainer _root = BuildContainers();

    public static RootContainer Root => _root;

    private static RootContainer BuildContainers()
    {
        LeafContainer Leaf = new LeafContainer();
        Child3Container Child3 = new Child3Container();
        Child2Container Child2 = new Child2Container();
        Child1Container Child1 = new Child1Container();
        RootContainer Root = new RootContainer();

        Root.Item = Child1;
        Child1.Item = Child2;
        Child2.Item = Child3;
        Child3.Item = Leaf;
        Leaf.IntItem = 12;

        IdToSearch = Root.Id;

        return Root;
    }

    public static IContainer? SearchContainer(Guid id)
        => SearchContainer(id, Root);

    public static IContainer? SearchContainer(Guid id, IContainer? fromContainer)
    {
        if (fromContainer == null) return null;
        if(fromContainer.Id == id)
            return fromContainer;
        if(fromContainer.IsLeaf)
            return null;
        return SearchContainer(id, fromContainer.Item);
    }
}
```

**Finally my `Program` :**

```
using TestRecursiveGenerics;

var res = ContainerUtils.SearchContainer(ContainerUtils.IdToSearch);

Console.WriteLine("Searching IContainer's Id, and we found : "+ res?.Name ?? "NULL");
```